# Backbone navigation/routes not working with Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

My index page loads correctly but when I click on the links my `'/notes/:id': 'showNote'`route does not work correctly. I am not sure if this is an issue with this route or if it is an issue with `Backbone.history.navigate(url, trigger: true)`. [I created screen cast of the problematic behavior here.](http://screencast.com/t/yQIO8gIWCc)

**routers/scratchpad_router.js.coffee**

```
class App.Routers.ScratchpadRouter extends Backbone.Router
  routes:
    '': 'index'
    '/notes/:id': 'showNote'

  index: ->
    view = new App.Views.Notes(collection: App.AllNotes)
    $('#container').html(view.render().el)

  showNote: (id) ->
     alert 'works'
```

**scratchpad.js.coffee**

```
window.Scratchpad =
  Models: {}
  Collections: {}
  Views: {}
  Routers: {}
  initialize: -> 
    @AllNotes = [
      {id: 1, title: "The first note", content: "I am indeed the very first of all notes"}
      {id: 2, title: "The second note", content: "There is nothing wrong with being second in note world"}
      {id: 3, title: "Get almond milk", content: "No sugar, not vanilla"}
    ]
    new @Routers.ScratchpadRouter
    Backbone.history.start(pushState: true)


window.App = window.Scratchpad

$(document).ready ->
  Scratchpad.initialize()
```

**views/notes.js.coffee**

```
class App.Views.Notes extends Backbone.View
  template: JST['notes/index']

  events: 
    'click a': 'showNote'

  render: ->
    @$el.html(@template(notes: @collection))
    this

  showNote: (e) ->
    $this = $(e.currentTarget)
    url = $this.attr("href")
    Backbone.history.navigate(url, trigger: true)
    return false
```

**../templates/notes/index.jst.eco**

```
<ul>
  <% for note in @notes: %>
    <li>
      <dl>
        <dt>Title</dt>
        <dd><a href="/notes/<%= note.id %>"><%= note.title %></a> </dd>
        <dt>Content</dt>
        <dd><%= note.content %></dd>
       </dl>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you check if you're using a gen called turbo link?

Answer (score 0):

I am suspecting that your problem lies within your click listener at:

```
showNote: (e) ->
    $this = $(e.currentTarget)
    url = $this.attr("href")
    Backbone.history.navigate(url, trigger: true)
    return false
```

I would firstly think that this event listener is not necessary, because it is pretty much doing the same thing that would happen if the user simply clicked on the , once you are using pushState = true.

I would suggest you commenting out this block and seeing if the issue persists. If the issue goes away I believe you can live without that block.